# Discard pickled cache when code changes (generate signature of python modules)

Tags: python, caching, pickle

I wrote an application that parses a massive amount of files into objects in memory. This is a very time-consuming action. When it's done, it saves the generated objects to pickled files. The second time I run it, it unpickles everything and only re-parses the files that have changed.

The codebase, however, is not stable, and it's not safe to simply define my software by a statically typed version number. I want to figure out if any of the code of my application has changed since I pickled the data, and if it did, discard the cache and rebuild it.

How do I generate a signature of a list of python modules? My first thought was pickling the  modules, but that doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried to use the timestamp of last modification of the files, or some kind of hash signature of the files? That could do the trick.

Comment: How about storing an md5 checksum of the original file along with the parsed objects? And maybe i'm missing something but what do you mean by "pickling the modules".

Comment: Huh exactly. How do I generate a MD5 checksum of the original file, since I don't even know WHERE it is (with ./setup.py putting it in a semi-arbitrary location, and possibly it existing only in .pyc format)?